# Product of tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7

As a Python newbie, it might be a silly question, but I can't find a solution.
I'm doing the product of a tuple, and working perfectly, like this:

```
list = list(itertools.product(["this", "the"],["example", "test"],["is not", "isnt"],[" working", "correct"]))
print(list)
```

But if a declare another variable, it does not work anymore:

```
test = ["this", "the"],["example", "test"],["is not", "isnt"],[" working", "correct"]
list = list(itertools.product(test))
print(list)
```

I checked with the `type()` function to get the class, and it's a tuple...

I'm running this in Python 3.x but I would like to make it compatible for 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it's bad to use `list` as a variable name, since this overwrites the default `list` function.

In your first, working, example, you pass multiple arguments to `itertools.product`, and it combines each argument to give the output you want. In your nonworking example, you only pass a single argument, the tuple `test`. Thankfully you can use Python's tuple unpacking syntax to expand each element of the tuple into an argument:

```
test = ["this", "the"],["example", "test"],["is not", "isnt"],[" working", "correct"]
# The * before test unpacks the tuple into separate arguments
result2 = list(itertools.product(*test))
print(result2)
[('this', 'example', 'is not', ' working'), ('this', 'example', 'is not', 'correct'), ('this', 'example', 'isnt', ' working'), ('this', 'example', 'isnt', 'correct'), ('this', 'test', 'is not', ' working'), ('this', 'test', 'is not', 'correct'), ('this', 'test', 'isnt', ' working'), ('this', 'test', 'isnt', 'correct'), ('the', 'example', 'is not', ' working'), ('the', 'example', 'is not', 'correct'), ('the', 'example', 'isnt', ' working'), ('the', 'example', 'isnt', 'correct'), ('the', 'test', 'is not', ' working'), ('the', 'test', 'is not', 'correct'), ('the', 'test', 'isnt', ' working'), ('the', 'test', 'isnt', 'correct')]
```

Comment: @BradTheBrutalitist are you suggesting I should add `import itertools` at the top of my answer? It wasn't shown in the original examples, so I assumed it was implied. Otherwise I'm not sure if I understand the question, can you clarify?

Comment: No I'm just saying I'm very foriegn to itertools.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I have a lot to learn about Python yet haha. And the name of the variables was just for a quick and dirty test.